# why when change array in structure all references change?

Tags: c#, list

I am working on C# project and my code is somthing like this:

```
public struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int[,] arr;
}
List<Point> po=new List<Point>();
void func()
{
    Point p1;
    p1.arr = new int[1, 1];
    p1.X = 10;
    p1.arr[0, 0] = 1;
    func2(p2);
    p1.X=20;
    p1.arr[0,0]=10;
 }
void func2(Point h)
    {
        po.Add(h);
    }
```

when I track this code and return from func2 , when change p1.x , my point in list (x parameter) not changed but when change p1.arr to 10,my point (arr parametr) in list also change from 1 to 10.why this happened an how can fix this problem?

Comment: It looks to me like you are only adding one value to the list object...

Comment: Where is `p2` coming from? Typo?

Comment: OP - What exactly are you trying to do here?  Add the values of one array to a list object?  Your code is very confusing.

Comment: also where is `p1.x` coming from?  did you mean `p1.X`?

Comment: Clearly the issue is related to not understanding the difference between value types and reference types, but none of us can figure out what you *actually* want to do.  The code makes it look like it's just an exercise to determine how value/reference types work.

Comment: @SamIam - Much like the code, my guess is that `x` was a typo.

Comment: OK, after re-reading this yet again, it appears that they're asking why, after adding a Point struct (p1) to a global List<Point> (po), and they then update p1's fields, why doesn't the struct in the list change. And as most of us have pointed out, it's because it's passed by value, not by reference. They could update it using po[someIndex].X, but that seems like a pain in the ass.

Comment: this code is part of my program and I simple it for question in this site.my problem is that seems structure have different manner for x and arr,structure deal whit x like value types but deal whit arr like reference type

Answer (score 2):

Structs have value semantics.  This means that changing p1.x is changing a value, not a reference.  You have a local value p1 that you are changing.  When you change a value *in* the array, you're changing that copy of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Structs are value types in C#, while classes are references. Try passing the point to func2 with the ref modifier.

```
void func2(ref Point h){
    ....
}
```

Actually, thanks to JG in SD's comment, it should be more like this:

```
void func2(ref Point po, Point h){
    po.Add(h);
}
```

And on further review, that's still wrong. Basically, when you're adding the Point to the List, it's copying the Point by value to the list.

p1 and po.Last() have the same values, but refer to different objects. If Point were a class, you wouldn't have this problem.

You could do this right after adding p1 to po, but it's dumb and unwieldy:

```
po.Add(p1);
var len = po.Count;
po[len-1].X = 20;
po[len-1].arr[0,0]=10;
```

You can't do:

```
po.Add(p1);
var len = po.Count;
var pNew = po[len-1]; 
// p1 and pNew are different objects in memory, but with the same values
pNew.X = 20;
pNew.arr[0,0]=10;
```

Well, technically, you can do exactly that, but since they're different objects in memory, it won't do what you're hoping.

Just switch Point to a class unless you have a serious need not to do so.

Comment: This won't work as you are thinking, as the value isn't passed by reference to `List<Point>.Add`.

Comment: @JGinSD: That's because the code as given won't compile in the first place. Where does po come from? I assumed that there should be a second Point parameter called po, which should be passed in as a ref, while h shouldn't be. Updating my answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: It was my understanding that `po` is a member variable that is declared before `func`.  But the underlying issue still exists, any changes made to the `Point` struct after it has been added to the list will not be reflected on the instance within the `List<Point>` as there is no `List<T>.Add(ref T item)` function.

Comment: I missed where po was declared. You're right. It would help if the question were clarified greatly.

Comment: thanks for answering but my problem is : though structure are value semantic , when p1.x change , that is right nothing happened for point that saved in list and this is what I want but when change p1.arr to whatever , arr in list also change and this is what I don't want.seems that there is a reference to that point saved in list and this is not good for my program.

Comment: @user2141833: Yes, I saw that after my first two answers and noted it in the comments.